# Removing two tables via parentnodes in Javascript simultaneously

Tags: javascript, forms, nodes

I've got this issue that seems confusing since the problem is basically more than half done- I'm able to remove form fields by clicking a link but it doesn't clear the complete form - just one out of the two tables. To demonstrate this point better, I've taken two screen shot images of the tables before and after clicking the "-" sign which is supposed to remove both of them but it removes only one! I can only remove the table above by clicking on the "-" sign above it in order to remove the entire form completely. I don't want to remove the entire form (two tables) in two clicks. I want them removed in just one click. Just one click of the "-" sign.

Note: Each form contains two tables of four rows - two rows/table - take a look at the pics below for further clarification!

Before clicking "-":

[image: Before clicking "-"]

After clicking "-":

[image: After clicking "-"]

Here's the Javascript function that I'm calling onclick in order to 
remove the tables -

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function removeFields1(elm1){
var tr1 = elm1.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
tr1.remove();
var tr = elm1.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
//getElementById("maywe");
tr.remove();

}
```

Here's the javascript code that I used in order create the "-" sign in the form fields when it was added to the table:

```
var td7a = document.createElement("td");
td7a.valign = "top";        
var remove1 = document.getElementById("Remove");        
remove1 = document.createElement("a");
remove1.id="Remove";
remove1.name="Remove";
remove1.href="#";
remove1.text="-";
remove1.onclick=function(){
removeFields1(this);};
td7a.appendChild(remove1);

tr.appendChild(td7a);
```

How can this matter be resolved?

P.S. Please focus on the `removeFields1(elm1){`function in the Javascript section in order to fix this issue.

P.S. I want the original form to stay- the forms are dynamically created....so the only 2 tables in the form that should be removed are the ones that I specifically click on deleting... they should delete two at a time...two tables/form

Comment: Can you show us the html code which is creating the page? Or did you do it entirely in Javascript. I don't know how many parent elements have been created, and since you are trying to remove an element 3 parents above the elm1 element I want to see the which element that is.

Comment: no problemo...sir - here's the entire code for you to analyze http://pastebin.com/c8AA1B3f

Comment: the above link includes the PHP/Javascript and HTML  code...hopefully this helps us to solve the problem! thanx!

Comment: anyone home? can nobody help me now?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you want to remove all tables in a form. So first find the form element and then find all child elements which are tables and then remove those. 
Following JS code may help you.

```
function removeFields1(elm1){
  parentFrm = findParentForm(elm1);
  var allTables = parentFrm.getElementsByTagName('table');  
  for(i=0;i<allTables.length;i++){
    allTables[i].remove(); 
  }
}
function findParentForm(elem){ 
  var parent = elem.parentNode; 
  if(parent && parent.tagName != 'FORM'){
    parent = findParentForm(parent);
  }
  return parent;
}
```

It will be good if you use Jquery to use predefined functions.

Comment: it only removes the very top node in the original form...i want the original form to stay- the forms are dynamically created....so the only 2 tables in the form that should be removed are the ones that I specifically click on deleting...they should delete two at a time...two tables/form